# How to initialize values in a large dataframe using a smaller dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataframe and I'd like to initialize a number of it's values using values from a smaller second dataframe. Referencing the following script for example:

```
# Creating small dataframe.
df.small <- data.frame(matrix("small", nrow = 5, ncol = 5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df.small

# Creating large dataframe.
df.large <- data.frame(matrix("large", nrow = 10, ncol = 10), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df.large

# Creating example of desired output.
# Note: this will only work if all values in small dataframe are the same
df.combined <- df.large
df.combined[1:5, 1:5] <- "small"
df.combined
```

If I have `df.small` and `df.large`, how can I initialize the values of indices [1:5, 1:5] of `df.large` with the values of `df.small` so that I get a dataframe that looks like `df.combined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,  `df.combined[1:5, 1:5] <- df.small[1:5, 1:5]`  ?

Comment: Yes that works. I didn't realize it was that simple.